# How to access Entity class from Sonata Admin's Admin class?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Let me explain: I have an Entity class Item with a method getName() in it, namespace App\Entity. I have an admin class for it in Sonata Admin, namespace App\Admin, and would like to call that method from within, how to do so?

```
//Symfony2 Entity
...
class Item
{
    public function getName(){
         return $this->name;
    }
}

...
//Sonata Admin class
class ItemAdmin extends Admin
{
  ...
  protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper){
     //how to access Item class' getName() method from here?
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** This works inside configureListFields(), but what about without find() and if with find() only, then how to automatically get 'id'?

```
 $item=$this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('Doctrine')->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')->find('15');
 echo $item->getName();
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do ? Actually in `configureListFields` there is not an Item instance already selected by the admin , you have to use `ListMapper` methods.

Comment: I want to do exactly what I wrote there, my Entity has a method, and I want to access it from inside configureListFields(). If there is no way to do this, It would be good to know that.

Comment: This function goals is to configure a list display, there is no `Item` selected by the `Admin`, no `id` selected, that's not the right place to do this.

Comment: @MuhammedM. you need elaborate more what you want to achieve ? i mean what you will do with `getName()` in `configureListFields()` function, what is the purpose behind that ?

Answer (score 8):

Simple and easy

```
$container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
$em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to get EntityManager:

```
   //Sonata Admin class
class ItemAdmin extends Admin
{
  ...
  protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper){
    $id = $this->getSubject()->getId();

    $em = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager(YourBundle:Item);
    $item = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Item')->find($id);
    $item->getName()
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager::getEntityManager(),

Comment: Your code doesn't work, I edited with my working version, maybe you want to work on that

Comment: how about $id ? how to automatically get that

Comment: I've updated answer. In your Admin class’ configureFormFields method you are able to get the current object by calling $this->getSubject(). The value returned will be your linked model.

Comment: didn't work, var_dump($this->getSubject());   -> boolean false

Comment: Do you need parent Id?

Comment: try $this->getRouterIdParameter() or $this->getParent()->getIdParameter();

Comment: id of the current processed row in configureListFields() . you wrote $id, in your answer, how are you going to get that?

Comment: You have to get this id from subject

Comment: What is the name of id parameter in your request?

Comment: *$id variable is for example. Admin class has method  $this->getRequest() you can try to get your id from request